# Finding an array of ids while keeping the order with Rails and PostGreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have an array of ids of objects that I want to get from the database, but PostGreSQL returns them sorted by ids:

```
Users.find([4, 1, 3])
=> [User 1, User 3, User 4]
```

I know I could sort them back like this:

```
ids = [4, 3, 1]
r = Users.find(ids)
users = ids.map{|id| r.detect{|each| each.id == id}}
```

But wouldn't it be better if I could do this with the database? I know MySQL has a "field" option. Does PostGreSQL has something equivalent?

Thank you,

Kevin

Comment: FYI, PostgreSQL does NOT "return them sorted by ids".  Either your ORM is sorting it or it just happened to come back in that order.  An unordered select from the database is not guaranteed to come back in any order and assuming it does will ultimately lead to odd behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This function will simulate the one from MySQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(anyelement, anyarray) RETURNS integer AS 
$body$
  SELECT COALESCE((
    SELECT i
    FROM generate_series(array_lower($2, 1), array_upper($2, 1)) s(i)
    WHERE $2[i] = $1
  ),0);
$body$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Example of usage:

```
CREATE TABLE x (id integer);
INSERT INTO x (1),(2),(3);
SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY field(id, ARRAY[3,1,2]);
 id 
----
  3
  1
  2
(3 rows)
```